# Is it possible to call wso2 message broker api from Java?

Tags: wso2, message-queue, wso2-message-broker

In my project, I am using on WSO2 Message Broker as a message brokering system.

I want to get some information like number of queues created, number of messages in queue and etc.. to display at my portal. To do this, I want to call message broker apis in my java class.

Can i call message broker apis in Java class ? If yes, Where can i get list of apis which can i use in my java code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information using the AndesAdminService. Code can be found at 
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-business-messaging/blob/master/components/andes/org.wso2.carbon.andes.admin/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/andes/admin/AndesAdminService.java

Comment: Please provide me any sample example, which is using AndesAdminService to get information. I am not getting, how should i call AndesAdminService class from my code. And what is the needed jar ?

Comment: you can create simple soap client using the wsdl and use that client/genarated stub to do so